# Grease Pencil animation behavior changed - keyframes don't override

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

I don't know how to explain this exactly. Ordinarily on a blank scene, drawing circles in succession and advancing a keyframe is the way to animate it. Upon advancing to a new frame and drawing, the previous frame's work is cleared and onionskinned, and seen below:

[image]

However, I'm not quite sure what happened but on a project that I have many hours in, this behavior has completely chnaged. Now, when I advance a frame and draw, the previous frame's work is maintained for the current frame. This means that I need to manually delete the previous frame's circle to create movement, otherwise it looks like the balls are being drawn in sequence, not moving.

Is there some setting to toggle this? I am animating characters and having to completely delete the character from the last frame is very irritating.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, I ended up clicking every single button on the screen and it turns out it's the snowflake near the top left labelled, "Use Additive Drawing." Turning this off brought back the original behavior.
[image]